# Laplace transform of x(t)^2*x'(t)

Tags: laplace-transform

I got a result that doesn't seem correct, so I'm hoping someone can tell me if I went wrong somewhere (probably with the integration by parts or in the second to last line).

$$
L(x(t)^2x'(t))=\int_{0}^{\infty} x(t)^2x'(t)e^{-st}dt
$$

So I use integration by parts with

$$
u=x(t)^2
$$
$$
dv=x'(t)e^{-st}dt
$$

Now my guess is this is where I went wrong and somehow misused the identity for the transform of the derivative of the function:

$$
du=2x(t)x'(t)dt
$$
$$
v=sX(s)-x(0)
$$

Then

$$
L(x(t)^2x'(t))=[sX(s)-x(0)][x(t)^2|_{0}^{\infty}-\int 2x(t)x'(t)dt]
$$
$$
=[sX(s)-x(0)][x(t)^2|_{0}^{\infty}-\int 2x(t)dx(t)]
$$
$$
=[sX(s)-x(0)][x(t)^2|_{0}^{\infty}-x(t)^2|_{0}^{\infty}]
$$
$$
=0
$$

If this result is indeed correct then that's a pretty shocking identity, otherwise hopefully someone can point out where I went wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that you should have left $v$ in terms of $t$ instead of plugging in the limits of integration immediately. Your integral term is wrong as a result (the other part involving $v$ is of course fine though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You integrate $dv$ the wrong way. Choose $u'=x'(t) x(t)^2$ and $v=e^{-st}$. Note that $u=\frac{x(t)^3}{3}$.